# Zsh file autocompletion with bare git repo

Tags: zsh, git, autocomplete

I have this in my .zshrc:

```
# command completion
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

usually letting me tab through commands, args, and files.

But with `git --git-dir=<the path> --work-tree="$HOME"` (usually aliased) it only works for sub-commands (like add and push) and args, not files. I'd like it to work with files too.

I tried putting it in a script like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

git --git-dir=<the path> --work-tree="$HOME" "$@"
```

and it works for files but then sub-commands and args break.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `--git-dir` is present on the command line, the completion code recognizes it and takes it into account when looking for things to complete, if your zsh is recent enough (≥5.3). It does so by passing the argument to `--git-dir` as the environment variable `GIT_DIR`. For example, to complete remote names after `git fetch`, zsh runs `git remote`. After `git --git-dir=/some/where`, zsh runs `git remote` with `GIT_DIR=/some/where` in the environment. So this part does work.

Unfortunately, as of the current zsh version (5.7.1+), it passes the *unexpanded* argument. So if you write something like `git --git-dir=~/repositories/foo.git`, zsh passes `GIT_DIR=~/repositories/foo.git`, not `GIT_DIR=/home/aaa/repositories/foo.git`.

The zsh completion code does not have similar support for `--work-tree`.

I think you can fix the expansion issue with `--git-dir` and add support for `--git-worktree` by editing the file `_git` and replacing the line

```
        (( $+opt_args[--git-dir] )) && local -x GIT_DIR=$opt_args[--git-dir]
```

by

```
        (( $+opt_args[--git-dir] )) && local -x GIT_DIR=${(e)~opt_args[--git-dir]}
        (( $+opt_args[--work-tree] )) && local -x GIT_WORKTREE=${(e)~opt_args[--work-tree]}
```

I haven't tested this.

I'm not sufficiently motivated to post to the zsh mailing list, but please do: this (or a working version of it, if it doesn't work) would be a useful patch.

If you put `--git-dir` or `--work-tree` in an alias, this is transparent: zsh expands aliases before doing completion (assuming you haven't turned off the option `complete_aliases`). If you put them in a function or in a script, this is opaque: zsh won't see them, and won't even know that the function or script calls git unless you tell it.

If you can't get this patch to work or you don't want to maintain your own version of `_git`, you can work around it by defining a custom command with a custom completion function that wraps around git.

```
gitx () {
  git --git-dir=/some/where --work-tree=/else/where "$@"
}
_gitx () {
  local -x GIT_DIR=/some/where GIT_WORKTREE=/else/where
  _git "$@"
}
compdef _gitx gitx
```

If you have multiple wrappers, you'll need a completion function for each one. Alternatively, you can add some logic to the completion function to figure out what value of `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORKTREE` to use. The name of the function is in `$service`.

Comment: Note that `echo --git-dir=~` outputs `--git-dir=~` unless you have the `magic_equal_subst` option enabled. IOW, that `~` is not *meant* to be expanded (by default)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas True, but if you want to treat this accurately, you have to distinguish between `--git-dir=~` which refers to a directory called `~` if `magic_equal_subst` is off from `--git-dir ~` which always refers to the home directory.

Comment: Note that `${(e)var}` turns `'$0'` into `'zsh'` for instance, and `$~var` `*` into the list of files in the current directory. `eval "GIT_DIR=$opt_args[--git-dir]"` would probably be slightly better, but would still expand command substitutions for instance (which as a use I wouldn't expect here).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Wouldn't `eval` crap out on word separators? Spaces are plausible; `<>|` and such are unlikely but dangerous. I'd like something close to `expand-word`, but I don't know if there's enough information to do this accurately inside a completion function.

Comment: If `$opt_args[--git-dir]` is meant to be the expanded token following `--git-dir`, I don't expect it would contain unquoted blanks.